# Program receives SIGABRT when setting an ivar

Tags: objective-c

```
[[self numSidesBox] setName: @"numSidesBox"];
```

This line of code receives the SIGABRT signal and i don't know why. numSidesBox is an instance of my subclass of UITextField. I have an NSString ivar that uses the

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

way of creating setters/getters. I have no idea what's causing this problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do.  Is numSidesBox the name of the UITextField?  What does the `name` do?

Comment: Have you synthesized the property?

Comment: the name ivar is only there so that i can specify a name for the textfield, so that other classes and objects can know which textField it's dealing with.

Comment: It would be more relevant if you posted the property declaration for *numSidesBox*, the synthesize, and the code where you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

`self.numSidesBox.name=@"numSidesbox"`

This assumes you have the following in your `numSidesBox` header:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString*name;`

and in your .m:

`@synthesize name;`

This is just a general idea to get you started and point you in the right direction; you might prefer something other than `retain` and will also need your `numSidesBox` object similarly synthesized in the current .h/.m to use dot notation on it.

Additionally, just because `numSidesBox` has an ivar, does not mean it actually exists in memory. Before you can use it, you have to at some point initialize it with `alloc` and `init` or a custom or dedicated initializer.